# Forwarding mDNS packets from an on-prem network to cloud server and back

Tags: networking, vlan, cloud, amazon-vpc, trunk

Problem Statement :

We have an application running on an on-prem Linux server configured with a trunk port and its working is tightly associated to multiple VLANs traffic and certain device IPs present on the same network. We are working on a solution to migrate this application to the cloud. This application requires the network traffic comprising of VLAN tagged packets and mDNS packets from the mentioned on-premise devices.

We had preformed an initial analysis by leveraging AWS (VPC , site-to-site VPN , Direct Connect) but we are currently facing difficulties migrating this application to the cloud as AWS does not provide options to create VLANs in their machines, associate a trunk port nor route mDNS traffic via VPN.

Queries :

- Are there any cloud platforms that can support the above scenario and solve this migration issue ?
- Any other possible solutions to tackle the migration of this app to cloud.